# Sharepoint 2010 Create PDF of document in document library

Tags: sharepoint, pdf, sharepoint-2010, pdf-generation

I have a document library in Sharepoint 2010. Is it possible to click on the check boxes next to a document name and convert the documents to pdf? I can't seem to find an option to do this. If not can I programmatically generate the pdf's and add them to the library.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if you have some programming skills you can create your own EventReceiver for every item added/updated to convert a word document to a PDF. By using Word Automation Services.

check this out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff181518.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a third party product as PDF Conversion doesn't come with SharePoint, unless you count the very basic MS-Word only conversion that is available in some editions of SharePoint 2010.

Have a look at [this product](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-for-SharePoint/summary.aspx), it does exactly what you want, including the checkboxes in SP2010, and can be used via workflows and web service calls as well.

Additional information as well as real world examples [can be found here](http://www.muhimbi.com/support/documentation/PDF-Converter-for-SharePoint/Code-Samples.aspx).

Disclaimer, I work for this vendor so it is a shameless plug. Yet it answers your question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Alice,

Or you can use dynamic PDF documents, which can be integrated with Document Library as content types. Have a look at [this product:](http://www.pdfsharepoint.com) it allows submitting Pdf forms using Adobe Reader (no Reader Extensions are necessary).

Disclaimer: I am using this product and happy with it. It has some limitations but nothing drastic.

Robert

Answer (score 0):

MS Word provides the convert function, you can open the Word document and save as PDF format in the document library.
Also, there are some third-part tools can help you to solve this issue, such as BoostSolutions PDF Converter.